# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Drones and Model Aircraft Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **May 18** to bring in your three inaugural pro-tem moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on May 18, users can [nominate themselves](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On May 25, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on June 2.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: On the page, you linked it says: "For these elections, the candidate questionnaire is an optional feature that individual sites can choose if they want". How is it decided if we are having a questionaire? Should a meta post be made about it?

Comment: Yup, that is up to y'all. I can help curate the final list of questions if help is needed though :)

Comment: I have created a post here: https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/pro-tempore-moderator-election-questionnaire/115#115 It serves as both an opinion as to whether there should be a questionnaire and a wiki post of potential questions, any suggestions? Should this feedback be gathered another way?

Comment: All candidates will have to provide a small introduction that will be made available [on the nomination page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/7), regardless of whether or not y'all do a questionnaire. If you do end up doing a questionnaire, though, generally speaking we first have [a question collection thread](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6536/33683), and from there compile the most relevant questions into [a questionnaire](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6561/33683) so the candidates can post their answers there.

Comment: Ok, there is a collection thread here: https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116/pro-tempore-moderator-election-question-suggestions